# How to get all rows from database table using ID from field with list of IDs in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, yii1.x

I am using PHP, Yii 1.1 and MySql to do a project.

I have a table `products` with fields `product_id`, `product_category_id`, `product_name`, `product_image`,  `product_description`, etc...

The `product_id` is the primary key and `product_category_id` contains the IDs of the categories which the product belongs to (it can take multiple ids like "1,3,4" as a string).

How can I get all the rows from that table, whose `product_category_id` contains a particular value?

For eg, if the table is like this:

```
|  product_id   |   product_category_id  |....
|      1        |           1,3,4        |....
|      2        |           2,5          |....
|      3        |           2,3,6        |....
```

and I need all the rows `product_category_id=3`, then it should  find me the first and third row.

Note: This is opposite function to

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product_category_id` IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function. Example for Yii 2.0:

```
$products = Product::find()
    ->andWhere(new Expresssion('FIND_IN_SET(:category_id, product_category_id)', [
        ':category_id' => $categoryId,
    ]))
    ->all();
```

Example for Yii 1.1:

```
$products = Product::model()
    ->findAll('FIND_IN_SET(:category_id, product_category_id)', [
        ':category_id' => $categoryId,
    ]);
```

> **`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`**
>
> Returns a value in the range of `1` to `N` if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of `N` substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by , characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type `SET`, the `FIND_IN_SET()` function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns `0` if `str` is not in `strlist` or if `strlist` is the empty string. Returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (`,`) character.

Comment: It worked for me. I used the function as follows: 
`$model= new Projects;$criteria=new CDbCriteria();$criteria->condition="t.status='1' and find_in_set( $cat_id, project_category_id) "; $project_model =$model->findAll($criteria);`

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT() in Mysql ; all rows in table add in one row;